# Astrometry of a CCD image with python

Tags: python, image-processing, astropy, astronomy

I am trying to implement a really easy astrometry code. I have manually found the coordinates of a couple of stars in my picture (RA/DEC and x/y in pixel).
Everything seems straight forward but I still get weird results, that are off by a couple of degrees.

I am trying to solve for the plate constants of a CCD image I took, where I found the stars coordinates and position in the picture by hand and now I want to try and find the (0,0) point's real worlds coordinates.

I hope someone can help me with my code or can tell me how to do it properly.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os

def astrometry(star_pos, xpix, ypix, focallength, target_RA, target_DEC):
    pi = np.pi
    DegToRad = pi / 180
    RadToDeg = 180 / pi
    n = len(star_pos)
    (target_RA, target_DEC) = (target_RA, target_DEC)
    print(target_RA, target_DEC)
    # 1) Obtain star coordinates in pixel and RA/DEC
    x_pix = [row[0] for row in star_pos]
    y_pix = [row[1] for row in star_pos]

    ra_star = [row[2] for row in star_pos]
    dec_star = [row[3] for row in star_pos]

    # 2) Calculate the standard coordinates of the stars
    X_star = np.zeros(n)
    Y_star = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        X_star[i] = -(np.cos(DegToRad*dec_star[i])*np.sin(DegToRad*(ra_star[i] - target_RA)))/(np.cos(DegToRad*target_DEC)*np.cos(DegToRad*dec_star[i])*np.cos(DegToRad*(ra_star[i]-target_RA)) + np.sin(DegToRad*target_DEC)*np.sin(DegToRad*dec_star[i]))
        Y_star[i] = -(np.sin(DegToRad*target_DEC)*np.cos(DegToRad*dec_star[i])*np.cos(DegToRad*(ra_star[i]-target_RA)) - np.cos(DegToRad*target_DEC)*np.sin(DegToRad*dec_star[i]))/(np.cos(DegToRad*target_DEC)*np.cos(DegToRad*dec_star[i])*np.cos(DegToRad*(ra_star[i]-target_RA)) + np.sin(DegToRad*target_DEC)*np.sin(DegToRad*dec_star[i]))

    # 3) Calculate the plate constants (Check my notes)
    def calc_plate_const(k,x,y,X):
        c_down = ((x[k+1]-x[k])*(y[k]*x[k+2]-y[k+2]*x[k])-(x[k+2]-x[k])*(y[k]*x[k+1]-y[k+1]*x[k]))
        c_up = (X[k]*x[k+1]*(y[k]*x[k+2]-y[k+2]*x[k])-X[k+1]*x[k]*(y[k]*x[k+2]-y[k+2]*x[k])-X[k]*x[k+2]*(y[k]*x[k+1]-y[k+1]*x[k])-X[k+2]*x[k]*(y[k]*x[k+1]-y[k+1]*x[k]))
        c = c_up/c_down
        print('c',c)
        b = ((X[k]*x[k+1]-X[k+1]*x[k])-(x[k+1]-x[k])*c)/(y[k]*x[k+1]-y[k+1]*x[k])
        print('b',b)
        a = (X[k]-b*y[k]-c)/x[k]
        print('a', a)
        return(a,b,c)

    (a,b,c) = calc_plate_const(0,x_pix,y_pix,X_star)
    (d,e,f) = calc_plate_const(0,x_pix,y_pix,Y_star)
    print(target_RA,target_DEC)
    # 4) Calculate the standard coordinates for the object
    # HIER object at (0,0)
    (x_ob, y_ob) = (0,0)
    X_ob = a*x_ob + b*y_ob + c
    Y_ob = d*x_ob + e*y_ob + f
    print('x', x_pix, x_ob, 'y', y_pix, y_ob)
    print('X', X_star, X_ob, 'Y', Y_star, Y_ob)
    print('RA', ra_star, 'DEC', dec_star)

    # 5) Calculate the RA/DEC of the objects standard coordinates
    a = target_RA + np.arctan(DegToRad*((-X_ob)/(np.cos(DegToRad*target_DEC)- Y_ob*np.sin(DegToRad*target_DEC))))
    d = target_DEC -  np.arcsin(DegToRad*((np.sin(DegToRad*target_DEC) + Y_ob*np.cos(DegToRad*target_DEC))/(np.sqrt(1 + X_ob**2 + Y_ob**2))))
    print('RA in rad', a, 'DEC in rad', d)
    print('RA',a,target_RA, 'DEC',d, target_DEC)

    return(a,d)
```

The Input is  for example an array with the stars position in pixel of the image  and degree of the real world

```
star pos = [[1948.2, 1205.8, 132.34058333333334, -3.4429722222222225], [153.90000000000001, 1892.5, 131.08620833333333, -5.0947499999999994]
# star_pos [x_pos in pix, y_pos in pix, RA, DEC]

(x_pix, y_pix) = (0.0135, 0.0135)
# pixel size

focallength = 0.7168

(target_RA, target_DEC) = (131.683014444 -3.91890194444)
# But I am not sure how accurate that is, it is more of an assumption. I would say if I look at the star map manually, it looks quite a bit off...
```

I would expect to see for the (0,0) point RA to be around 133° and DEC -5.75°

Comment: To stand any chance of helping you need to provide some sample input data that reproduces the problem you are having - and the output your code generates plus expected/correct output.

Comment: Nor would it be luxury to explain what you are trying to do. We don't read your mind.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry about that. I am all new to this...
I now added my entries and I am expection an urput of 133 and - 5.75
Thanks for taking a look at it :-)

Comment: I've looked around, and I can't find a pre-packaged solution to your problem. Try looking up "Procrustes analysis," which is a way to map a collection of points to another collection of points. This will have some shortcomings (namely, I expect it will fail on a sphere, which is how astronomical images are embedded), but you may be able to make something work. In general, astronomers use WCS (world coordinate system) to calibrate their frames' astrometry. Lastly, Hogg et al. have written a tool, astrometry.net, that does some of this. You might give it a try.

Comment: @TheresaOtt you need a third star in the `star_pos` list to make the transformation, am I right? Your question currently lists only two.

Comment: @TheresaOtt also, your `star pos` list is badly pasted.